# Sqoop export not picking manually created file while exporting data to mysql

Tags: mysql, sqoop

`Sqoop` export not picking manually created file while exporting data to `mysql`.

- I have imported few rows from `mysql` to `hdfs` using the `sqoop` import command (to location /user/cloudera/cities).
- I then added a new file in `hdfs` and want to update back to `mysql` table cities.
- But `sqoop` only exporting previously imported data, skipping the new data I have inserted manually.

`Sqoop` export command below:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/sqoop \
--username sqoop \
--password sqoop \
--table cities \
--export-dir /user/cloudera/cities \
--update-key id
```

Kindly help me understand if i miss anything.

Comment: Adding update-mode allowinsert solved the problem

Comment: @PrasanthBabu Does the file have same format, same schema ? and make sure that IDs of the added file are in harmony with other files.

Comment: @dev im trying to export data from hdfs to mysql, i didnt used update-mode to allowinserts which solved the problem.

Comment: @54l3d format and id's are fine, the problem was above command just updates the existing rows and ignores the inserts. Thanks